# jQuery how to undo a select change

Tags: jquery

I have a select box, and I'd like to add a confirm before changing it to a specific option. Example:

```
<select name="select">
    <option value="foo" selected="selected">foo</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();

    if (selected == 'bar') {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            // set back to previously selected option
        }
    }
});
```

I'm thinking about adding a hidden input field and update its value every time the select is changed. That way I can retrieve the previous value in the `change` function. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eUM4D/):

```
<input type="hidden" name="current" value="foo" />
```

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    var current = $('input[name=current]').val();

    if (selected == 'bar') {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            $(this).val(current);
            return false;
        }
    }

    $('input[name=current]').val(selected);
});
```

Is there an easier/better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Rather than using a global variable (evil!) or a hidden element (abuse of the DOM) you can use the [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) feature:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();

    if (selected == 'bar') {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            $(this).val($.data(this, 'current'));
            return false;
        }     
    }

    $.data(this, 'current', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that one. Very useful and works great! Thanks.

Comment: Good work. Does it need an additional line outside to initialize 'current' with the initial value, and was $(this).data() not available in 2010?

Comment: To initialize 'current' with the initial value, I switched to $(this).data(…) instead of $.data(this,…) and then added to my script: if( $('select').length > 0 ) { $('select').data('current', $('select').val()); }

Comment: or use `$(this).data('key', val)` which seems like cleaner syntax to me.  Oops, @TolandHon already noted that.  Upvote for him!

Comment: This does not work with Select2 dropdown, when i choose Cancel, it still is picking new value

Comment: Just want to add that regarding initialization it seems to work fine for me to just add attribute data-current="myStartingOptionValue" to the <select> element. No need for script initialization.

Comment: This is great but there is on caveat. An input's value is not always accurate for what's selected as often the browser will cache the current selected option. For example on refresh or posting to the same page.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this would help.

```
$( YOUR_SELECT_ELEMENT ).on({
    "ready": function (e) {
        $(this).attr("readonly",true);
    },
    "focus": function (e) {
        $(this).data( { choice: $(this).val() } );
    },
    "change": function (e) {
        if ( ! confirm( "Change selected option, proceed?" ) ){
            $(this).val( $(this).data('choice') );
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).attr("readonly",false);
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not sure 'return false' is effective for remove the attribute 'readonly'.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be the another way to achieve same.This code will also undo select change.

```
   <div class="selection">

          <input type="radio" class="selected" value="test1" name="test1" 
          checked="checked" /><label>test1</label>

          <input type="radio" name="test1" value="test2" /><label>
          test2</label>

          <input type="radio" name="test1" value="test3" /><label>
          test3</label>

    </div>

     $("input[name='test1']").change(function() {
            var response = confirm("do you want to perform selection change");
            if (response) {
                var container = $(this).closest("div.selection");
                //console.log(container);
                //console.log("old sel =>" + $(container).find(".selected").val());
                $(container).find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                //console.log($(this).val());
                console.log("new sel =>" + $(container).find(".selected").val());
            }
            else {
                var container = $(this).closest("div.selection");
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
                $(container).find(".selected").prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('change','.change_response_status',function()
{
    var responseStatusId = this.id;
    var responseID = $("#"+responseStatusId).attr('data-id');
    var previouesSatatus = $("#hidden_response_id_"+responseID).val();
    var confirmstatus = confirm("Are you sure you want to change status for this item?");
    var currentSelectedValue = $(this).val();

    if(confirmstatus==true)
    {
        $("#hidden_response_id_"+responseID).val(currentSelectedValue);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).val(previouesSatatus);
        $("#hidden_response_id_"+responseID).val(previouesSatatus);
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-id="2" id="response_id_2" class="change_response_status" name="status">
    <option value="1">Accept</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">No Respond</option>
    <option value="3">Reject</option>
</select>
<input class="hidden_response_class" id="hidden_response_id_2" type="hidden" value="1" name="hidden_response_staus">
```

This is best way to display already selected option on click with using cancel on confirmation box.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more verbose and commented version of lonesomeday's accepted answer that prompts for confirm on each change and uses `.data()` rather than `jQuery.data()`.

It might help people with understanding the logic a bit more.

Accompanying jsFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/xpvt214o/63508/).

```js
// set the initial data value
$(document).ready(function() {
  var my_select = $("#my_select");
  my_select.data("current", "foo");
});

// when selecting another option
$('select').change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var selected = $this.val();

  logit($this, selected, 1); // log data to screen

  // if clicking cancel on the confirm dialog
  if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    logit($this, selected, 2); // log data to screen

    // set the select's value to the stored data value
    var previous_data_value = $(this).data("current");
    $this.val(previous_data_value);
    // escape the onchange function 
    return false;
  }

  // if clicking OK, update the data value to the chosen option
  logit($this, selected, 3); // log data to screen

  $this.data("current", $this.val());

});




// helper functions only below

$(document).on("click", ".clicker", function() {
  var my_select = $("#my_select");
  alert(my_select.data("current"));
});


function logit($this, selected, instance) {
  var current_data_value = $this.data("current");
  if (instance === 1) {
    var value_log = "<span>you selected the value: " + selected + "</span>";
    $(".container_2").append(value_log);
    var data_log = "<span>the previous value was: " + current_data_value + "</span>";
    $(".container_2").append(data_log);
  } else if (instance === 2) {
    $(".container_2").append("<span>you clicked Cancel, value was reverted to: " + current_data_value + "</span>");

  }
  if (instance === 3) {
    $(".container_2").append("<span>you clicked OK, value was changed from '" + current_data_value + "' to '" + selected + "'</span>");
  }

  $(".container_2").append("<span>------------------------------------------------------</span>");
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.clicker {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.container_1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  background: lightgray;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.container_1:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  display: block;
}

.container_2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #222;
}

span {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: lime;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container_1">

  <select id="my_select">
<option value="foo">foo</option>
<option value="bar">bar</option>
<option value="baz">baz</option>
</select>
  <button class="clicker">what's the data value now?</button>
</div>

<div class="container_2">


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Select2, you can use something below,

```
$('select').on('select2:selecting', function() {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you?')) {
         $(this).select2('close')
         return false
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Oldschool way (before we used jquery):

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="if(confirm('Do you really want to change?')){ doSomething(); } else { this.selectedIndex=myIndex; }">
    <option value="foo" selected="selected">foo</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myIndex = $('mySelect').selectedIndex;
</script>
```

Comment: You are using jquery there!? LOL

Comment: No, it was prototype :P