# jQuery - cancel change event on confirmation dialog for a Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown and I have the jQuery `change` function.

I would like to implement the change of the selected item as per the Confirmation dialog.

If confirms true i can proceed for selected change otherwise I have keep the existing item as selected and cancel the change event.

How can I implement this with jQuery?

jquery Function

```
$(function () {
    $("#dropdown").change(function () {
        var success = confirm('Are you sure want to change the Dropdown ????');
        if (success == true) {
            alert('Changed');  
            // do something                  
        }
        else {
            alert('Not changed');
            // Cancel the change event and keep the selected element
        }
    });
});
```

One thing to remember `change` function hits only after selected item changed
So better to think to implement this on `onchange` - but it is not available in jquery. Is there any method to implement this?

Comment: This looks like a better approach than using a global variable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3963959/47167

Answer (score 51):

Well, as Vinu has rightly pointed out, jQuery's `change` event is only triggered once the value of the select has actually been changed. You would be better off doing something like this:

```
var prev_val;

$('#dropdown').focus(function() {
    prev_val = $(this).val();
}).change(function() {
     $(this).blur() // Firefox fix as suggested by AgDude
    var success = confirm('Are you sure you want to change the Dropdown?');
    if(success)
    {
        alert('changed');
        // Other changed code would be here...
    }  
    else
    {
        $(this).val(prev_val);
        alert('unchanged');
        return false; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I was posting mine when you posted yours. I didn't see it until I refreshed the page...

Comment: Upvoting this one. It will also work if the user is using Tab to navigate the page unlike the previous one.

Comment: This isn't working for me on Firefox (not tried anything else). For some reason the focus event is re-triggered when confirm box is confirmed/canceled and before change is triggered resulting in an incorrect value for prev_val. Works fine with click.

Comment: IIRC, certain browsers take focus away from inputs while a modal dialog is presented. Probably Firefox is restoring focus once you confirm it, so is running the function again. Before showing the confirm, try removing focus from the field.

Comment: BenM is correct in his comment about removing focus.  Use $(this).blur()

Comment: This triggers twice in Chrome. Once on focus and another on blur (because the field changed). The change event should removed after the alert triggered on success

Comment: If you change the menu one first time with success, and try a second time with fail, it will go back to the first state, and not the second. It's because the select did'nt loose the focus, so the focus event is not called the second time. You'll have to set the new `prev_val` in `if(success)`

Answer (score 24):

Something like what I did here?

http://jsfiddle.net/Swader/gbdMT/

Simply save the value as soon as a user clicks the select box, and revert back to this value if the onchange confirmation returns false.

Here is the code from my fiddle:

```
var lastValue;

$("#changer").bind("click", function(e) {
    lastValue = $(this).val();
}).bind("change", function(e) {
    changeConfirmation = confirm("Really?");
    if (changeConfirmation) {
        // Proceed as planned
    } else {
        $(this).val(lastValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hai Swader, I works... and thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 5):

Use following code,I have tested it and its working

```
var prev_val;
$('.dropdown').focus(function() {
    prev_val = $(this).val();
}).change(function(){
            $(this).unbind('focus');
            var conf = confirm('Are you sure want to change status ?');

            if(conf == true){
                //your code
            }
            else{
                $(this).val(prev_val);
                $(this).bind('focus');
                return false;
            }
});
```

Comment: bind has been depreciated use just $(this).focus() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is implemented for radio button.I think this code with minor changes can be used for drop down also.

```
      <input type="radio" class="selected" value="test1" name="test1" 
      checked="checked" /><label>test1</label>

      <input type="radio" name="test1" value="test2" /><label>
      test2</label>

      <input type="radio" name="test1" value="test3" /><label>
      test3</label>

</div>

 $("input[name='test1']").change(function() {
        var response = confirm("do you want to perform selection change");
        if (response) {
            var container = $(this).closest("div.selection");
            //console.log(container);
            //console.log("old sel =>" + $(container).find(".selected").val());
            $(container).find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            //console.log($(this).val());
            console.log("new sel =>" + $(container).find(".selected").val());
        }
        else {
            var container = $(this).closest("div.selection");
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
            $(container).find(".selected").prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to handle it yourself, this might help:

```
<select onFocus="this.oldIndex = this.selectedIndex" onChange="if(!confirm('Are you sure?'))this.selectedIndex = this.oldIndex">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it like

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    var success = confirm('Are you sure want to change the Dropdown ????');
    if (success == true) {
        // do something                  
    }
    else {
        return false; // will set the value to previous selected
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Blurring, focusing and storing previous values seems a bit cumbersome.  I solved this problem by attaching my listener not to the select, but to the option:

```js
$("#id").on('mousedown','option',confirmChange);
```

then,

```
function confirmChange(e){
    var value = $(this).val(),
        c = confirm('Are you sure you want to change?');

    if(c)
        $(this).parent().val(value);//can trigger .change() here too if necessary
    else
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

Of course optimizations can be done, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Yes, good but just like to notice this miss the case where you change the select dynamically with code.