# Reverting dropDownChoice value if precondition is negative

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I have a `DropDownChoice` element on my Wicket panel. I use precondition to check if user really wants to change the value on the element. No update is called when you answer no to confirmation, but the state of `dropField` is still changed and the selected item is as value on the element in ui.

I want to revert to the old status (maybe got from model) when precondition fails. OnUpdate immediatedly submits value, so having after cancel the old value visible is wrong, because it does not anymore reflect database status of the variable.

Where I should place my confirm dialog so that I can on cancel / no answer revert the state of the ui element? Or is it possible with the `onPrecondition`listener somehow?

```
dropField.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @Override
       protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
           super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
           AjaxCallListener listener = new AjaxCallListener();
           listener.onPrecondition("return confirm('" + "foo" + "');");
           attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(listener);
       }

       protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
          ..
       }
}
```

**Edit:**

My current solution is to show a modal with abstract onAccept() method to ask the confirmation and then inside onUpdate() I call it and implement the logic to save or in onCancel() I do revert.

```
protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    ConfirmModal modal = new ConfirmModal() {
       @Override
       protected void onAccept() {
           ..save..
       }

       @Override
       protected void onCancel() {
           ..revert..
       }
    }

     target.add(modal);
}
```

As you see, I end onUpdate() method to adding new panel to target, not to change anything.

My solution is to give new value to modal as parameter and in `onAccept()` I can use that value. Also I save to same file where `dropField` lies the old value, as it is also forgotten in this process.

Also target to put the `dropField` after update I need to access target like

```
AjaxRequestTarget target = RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class);
```

As you see, this is quite a hacksy way, still waiting for better insights.

**Edit2:**

A more complete example code:

```
String oldValue;

protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    ConfirmModal modal = new ConfirmModal(theElement.getModeObject()) {
       @Override
       protected void onAccept() {
           theElement.setModelObject(getValue());
           oldValue = getValue();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onCancel() {
           theElement.setModelObject(oldValue);
       }
    }

     target.add(modal);
}
```

Comment: This is rather a JavaScript/jQuery question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677744/jquery-cancel-change-event-on-confirmation-dialog-for-a-dropdown#answer-6677897

Comment: `listener.onPrecondition()` is the only place where I could place javascript, IMHO jQuery there is not an option.

Comment: Actually I started working on a full java solution to make confirm as a modal, then there are buttons and onClick targets, where adding java tricks is more like trivial.

I will give the answer when I get all parts done.

Comment: My only problem now is the code in edit2 seems to me little bit hacksy, so if better ideas are there, I am open to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved old value to variable and set it back after canceled confirmation message.

Solution is pure java, hacksy, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java/Wicket solution is too chatty. It makes two Ajax calls while if you use plain JavaScript there won't be any. 
The problem is that you use 'change' event that is fired *after* the change of the values. See the link by @svenmeier in the comments with an explanation and a solution. You can also try with 'click' event.