# How to open a Bootstrap Modal on change of select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open a modal on the change event of select Box?

This is My Modal

```
<!-- Modal when adding comment for upload -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="fileUploadModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add Comment</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p><textarea id = "commentsUpload"class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitXYX()" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And select Box is:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id = "selectNEWBox">
    <option value = "1">New</option>
    <option value = "2">Old</option>
    <option value = "3">Scrap</option>
</select>
```

What I need to do is to open the **Modal** on change event of select Box.

***What I have tried***

In `$(document).ready(function () {});`

**Approach 1**

```
$("#selectNEWBox").change(function(){
    $('#fileUploadModal').modal({
    show: true
  });
});
```

**Approach 2**

```
$("#selectNEWBox").change(function (){
    $('#fileUploadModal').modal('show');
});
```

but these are not working.

Am I missing something?

Comment: any error you received in console ?

Comment: Other than a missing semicolon at the end '.modal('show')', your code seems to be ok. Can you provide a working fiddle of the issue.

Comment: works fine: http://www.codeply.com/go/hMooZk56uc

Comment: have you add bootstrap js and css library ??

Comment: did you load jquery: because your code works - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2cxqqst1/)

Comment: Does the 'selectpicker' have another change event handler?

Comment: @RAJNIKPATEL : I am getting this error TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - cancel change event on confirmation dialog for a Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677744/jquery-cancel-change-event-on-confirmation-dialog-for-a-dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

just tried your code and it seem working

```
$( "#selectNEWBox" ).change(function() {
  $('#fileUploadModal').modal('show')
});
```

try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rixlabs/0gywjh8n/2/)

Comment: changed the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the issue.
It seems the issue was because of conflict of Jquery versions.

Removed the conflict and it's working now. :)