# Combobox change event to revert back to value before change

Tags: jquery

I need to detect the selected value of a comboBox and if a certain value is selected produce a confirm dialog. If the confirm is false, I need to revert back to the value before the change took place. I'm trying with a hidden field that holds the value before the change. this is not working...

UPDATE: when I addede the alert to see if the value was actually being set in the hidden field, everything works fine. If I remove the alert the change never happens. Some kind of timing issue? I replaced the alert with a delay and it didnt fix anything. Any ideas whats going on?

```
jQuery('#cboCityID1').focus(function() {
    if(jQuery('#cboCityID1').val() != '') {
        jQuery('#hiddencity1').val(jQuery('#cboCityID1').val()); 
    }
});

jQuery('#cboCityID1').change(function() {

    alert("as debug 1: " + jQuery('#hiddencity1').val());

    if(jQuery('#cboCityID1').val() == '') {
        var r = confirm("Are you sure");
        if(!r) {
            jQuery('#cboCityID1').val(jQuery('#hiddencity1').val()); 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the hidden input!

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963855/jquery-how-to-undo-a-select-change) suggested using `$.data` like so:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();

    if (selected == 'bar') {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            $(this).val($.data(this, 'current')); 
            return false;
        }     
    }

    $.data(this, 'current', $(this).val());
});
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miken118/baKCD/) using the suggested approach (no hidden inputs)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    var previous;    
    $("select").focus(function () {
        previous = this.value;
    }).change(function() {    
       var r = confirm("Are you sure");
    if(!r)        
        $('#cboCityID1').val(jQuery('#hiddencity1').val(previous )); 

    });
})();
```