# Undo dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Please can someone tell me why the 'return false' statement does not work in the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/mattkoen/8149m5kg/

```
<select id="userTypes" title="Choose a user type">
    <option value="0">Choose a user type</option>
    <option value="superu">Super U</option>
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select>

$('#userTypes').change(function () {

    if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: what u want to achieve ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery how to undo a select change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963855/jquery-how-to-undo-a-select-change)

Answer (score 1):

Returning `false` doesn't undo the select, instead it acts as both `event.preventDefault` and `event.stopPropogation`. You need this, instead.

```
if (!confirm("Are you sure?")){
    $(this).val($(this)[0].initialValue); // now it undos the select.
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8149m5kg/1/)

Comment: Close, but it changes it to the initial value as opposed to *last* selected value (undo)