# Onchange event isn't being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to prevent users from being able to select the same value on multiple select boxes, however my javascript event doesn't seem to be working.

Here's what I have:

**prioritize_change_handler.js**

```
$(function ChangeHandler(){
  $("#character_first_stat").on('change', function() {
    if ($("#character_second_stat").val() === $(this).val() && this.value !== " ") {
      $(this).val(" ");
      alert("Value is the same as the second stat!")
    }
    if ($("#character_third_stat").val() === $(this).val() && this.value != " ") {
      $(this).val(" ");
      alert("Value is the same as the third stat!")
    }
    if ($("#character_fourth_stat").val() === $(this).val() && this.value != " ") {
      $(this).val(" ");
      alert("Value is the same as the fourth stat!")
    }
    if ($("#character_fifth_stat").val() === $(this).val() && this.value != " ") {
      $(this).val(" ");
      alert("Value is the same as the fifth stat!")
    }
    if ($("#character_sixth_stat").val() === $(this).val() && this.value != " ") {
      $(this).val(" ");
      alert("Value is the same as the sixth stat!")
    }
  });
```

The code repeats like this for the remaining 5 dropdowns, changing the id to the correct IDs.

Here's the view/partial that I am trying to apply it to:

**_rand_prompt_step.html.erb**

```
<label for="character_first_stat">First Stat: </label>
    <select id="character_first_stat" name="character[first_stat]"  >
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" hidden value=""> </option>
        <option value="strength">strength</option>
        <option value="dexterity">dexterity</option>
        <option value="constitution">constitution</option>
        <option value="intelligence">intelligence</option>
        <option value="wisdom">wisdom</option>
        <option value="charisma">charisma</option>
    </select>
    <span><%= @character.errors[:first_stat][0] %></span>
```

It repeats like this for the remaining 5 dropdowns, using the correct IDs.

I have applied this line to the beginning of the view that calls the partial above.

```
<script src="/assets/prioritize_change_handler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've even resorted to using html instead of rails to attempt to get it to work, but I just can't seem to be able to call it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a thought, but if you prevent people from selecting a stat that has been selected before it will make it difficult for people to change their minds, as they will have to deselect a stat before switching another, if you follow me. Maybe it would be better to highlight the fact the two have been selected and prevent the form being submitted rather than preventing stats being the same?

Comment: relevant question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963855/jquery-how-to-undo-a-select-change

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is you're invoking an anonymous function.

In standard JS, this would probably work okay... but as you're using Rails, the likelihood is that it's not being invoked.

Thus, you'll want to use the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "select.add_class", function() {
   var parent_val = $(this).val();
   var others = $("select.add_class").not(this);

   $.each(others, function(i,v){
      if (parent_val == $(this).val() && this.value !== " ") {
         // do something here
      }
   }
});
```

This [delegates the `on` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) from your `document` object, allowing the JS to catch the request each time it loads.

Answer (score -1):

you can refactor the jquery function as following,

```
$(function() {
  var selects = $('#first, #second, #third');
  selects.on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      duplicateFound = false,
      val = $this.val();
    selects.not($this).each(function(i, sel) {
      if ($(sel).val() === $this.val() && this.value !== "") {
        $this.val($this.data('val'));
        return duplicateFound = true;
      }
    });
    if (duplicateFound) return;
    $this.data('val', val);
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgssdmd8/)

Hope this helps,

Answer (score -1):

I would refactor the js to make it more dynamic. https://jsfiddle.net/0z59sva3/

```
$(function(){
  var $selects = $('.add-a-class-to-the-selects');

  $selects.on('change', function(){
    // get all your local variables
    var 
      $this     = $(this),
      val       = $this.val(),
      offset    = $this.offset(),
      $others = $selects.not(this);
    // find any duplicate options
    $others.each(function(){
      var $other   = $(this),
          otherVal = $other.val();
      if( otherVal && val === otherVal ){
        alert('selected value matches: ' + $other.attr('id') );
        $this.val('');
      }
    });
  });
});
```