# Unselect last option from multiselect box in iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jquery code to limit the selection in multi-select box. It is working fine in any android device but problem occurs in iphone.

In iphone the alert message is shown but the last selected element doesn't deselected as expected. It should shows the 3 items selected but it shows the 4 items selected after alert message occurred in iphone. Any hint appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```
<select id="mob-industry">
  <option value="1">Web Development</option>
  <option value="2">Architecture</option>
  <option value="3">Software Development</option>
  <option value="4">Hardware</option>
</select>


var last_valid_selection = null;
$('#mob-industry').change(function(event) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 3) {
        sweetAlert("","Only 3 Allowed","info");
          $(this).val(last_valid_selection);
    } else {
          last_valid_selection = $(this).val();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Did you try returning false when more than 3 is selected?

Comment: yes i tried, but no luck :(

Comment: There is another way to undo selection using $.data.. Plz refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963855/jquery-how-to-undo-a-select-change

Comment: Also did you try removing the sweetAlert? If there is an error with sweetAlert  on iphone they the next line may not be executed.

Comment: Yes i have removed that too, let me check with $.data

Comment: Ok check the updated answer

Comment: @Siva no luck with $.data

Comment: Check the updated comments/code.

Comment: Answer works now and is solid. Try it out.

Comment: For the sake of trying to solve the original problem, I think that maybe iphone is not handling setting .val() for a multiselect due to the array. Try putting `selected` on all the options in your html and then `alert($("#mob-industry").val());` and see what it spits out. My guess is it won't be the list you think.

Comment: Added another way to do the same thing, but is a little shorter. I don't like it as much because it doesn't catch the flicker on select.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you got your method from something like: [How do you limit options selected in a html select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046205/how-do-you-limit-options-selected-in-a-html-select-box)

But I think this is what you really want/should use:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<select id="mob-industry" multiple>
    <option value="1">Web Development</option>
    <option value="2">Architecture</option>
    <option value="3">Software Development</option>
    <option value="4">Hardware</option>
</select>

$('#mob-industry').bind("vmousedown", function(event) {
    var num_selected = $(this).find(":selected").length;
    if (num_selected == 3) {
        var last_selected_value = $(event.target).val();
        var select_array = $(this).val();
        if ($.inArray(last_selected_value, select_array) == -1) {
            alert("YOU SHALL NOT PASS!!!");
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle (uses mousedown() instead of .bind("vmousedown") for compatibility with computer): https://jsfiddle.net/kpm0yLyt/1/

JsDoIt (mobile simulation, though some quirky bug with showing the options as you pick them. Ignore that.):  http://jsdo.it/Macainian/GKxn

Oh btw, alternative way to do it (uses click() instead of .bind("vclick") for compatibility with computer): https://jsfiddle.net/m49wr4t1/5/

Comment: This doesn't prevent the selection

Comment: @Macainian with this code i am able to select as many options as i want

Comment: Ok there we go. Fixed it and tested it this time. :) Also added the jsfiddle

Comment: Lol. Forgot. Use touchstart instead

Comment: Though I don't know if there is touchstart(), you might have to do on("touchstart" function(){});

Comment: I can't really test it, so if you find out, let me know so I can adjust the answer if needed.

Comment: yeah , give me a mintue i am testing it

Comment: @Macainian no luck it just allow me to select as many as i want

Comment: So the code I suggested works on Android but let's you select as many as you want on iphone? If that is the case, then maybe there is something else going on. Have you checked for javascript errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104619/discussion-between-prince-gautam-and-macainian).

Comment: @PrinceGautam Ok finally got it right this time. Found a site to test mobile.

Comment: @PrinceGautam I noticed a bug with this. You couldn't deselect ones that you selected after reaching 3, so messed around and found a solution for that. This is rock solid now. Try it out.

Comment: @PrinceGautam If you aren't convinced, I added the jsdoit for it which does mobile simulation.